# How to create bean with "request" and "schedule" scopes at one time?

Tags: java, spring, scope, scheduled-tasks

I have `UsersHandledInRequestCache` bean which is using for caching during request:

```java
@Configuration
public class CacheConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @RequestScope
    public UsersHandledInRequestCache usersHandledInRequestCache() {
        return new UsersHandledInRequestCache();
    }

    public static class UsersHandledInRequestCache {
        private final Set<Integer> cachedUsersIds = new HashSet<>();

        public void cache(Integer userId) {
            this.cachedUsersIds.add(userId);
        }

        public boolean isCached(Integer userId) {
            return this.cachedUsersIds.contains(userId);
        }
    }
}
```

And i have a service which uses the bean:

```java
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Resource(name = "usersHandledInRequestCache")
    private CacheConfiguration.UsersHandledInRequestCache usersHandledInRequestCache;

    public void doSomething(Integer userId) {
        if (!usersHandledInRequestCache.isCached(userId)) {
            // do something
            usersHandledInRequestCache.cache(userId);
        }
    }
}
```

So the service can be called by controllers and there are no problems:

```java
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    private final UserService userService;

    @PostMapping
    public void doSomething(@RequestBody Collection<Integer> usersIds) {
        usersIds.forEach(userService::doSomething);
    }
}
```

In this case `UsersHandledInRequestCache` bean is creating for each request and works correct. But additionaly i have scheduled service:

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserJob {
    
    private final UserService userService;

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 7 * * *")
    public void doSomething() {
        userService.getSomeUsersIds.forEach(userService::doSomething);
    }
}
```

And when the scheduled service is starting to work i get exception due to field `UserService#usersHandledInRequestCache` can not be initialized *(because there are no any requests and method calling is initiated by scheduled service work)*:

> Error creating bean with name
> 'scopedTarget.usersHandledInRequestCache': Scope 'request' is not
> active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for
> this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested
> exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request
> found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual
> web request, or processing a request outside of the originally
> receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request
> and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside
> of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or
> RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.

I want to make bean `UsersHandledInRequestCache` with "request" scope and "schedule" scope at one time. How i can get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The above error occurs because the spring request scope is only registered for web app requests.**

Through the implementation of the [`RequestAttribute`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestAttributes.html) interface, spring puts/gets the request scope information from `HttpRequest`.

If the thread was started outside of the web request, the thread does not have the required attributes in its variables and hence throws exception.

I ran into the same problem - needed to execute code in the job using `@Scheduled`, so it was unable to use any Session or Request scope beans.

There are couple of ways to solve this problem, I solved it the following way:

###### Implement RequestAttributes Interface:

```java
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestAttributes;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class CustomRequestAttribute implements RequestAttributes {

    private Map<String, Object> requestAttributes = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public Object getAttribute(String name, int scope) {
        if (scope == RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST) {
            return this.requestAttributes.get(name);
        } else return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAttribute(String name, Object value, int scope) {
        if (scope == RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST) {
            this.requestAttributes.put(name, value);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void removeAttribute(String name, int scope) {
        if (scope == RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST) {
            this.requestAttributes.remove(name);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getAttributeNames(int scope) {
        if (scope == RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST) {
            return this.requestAttributes.keySet().toArray(new String[0]);
        } else return new String[0];
    }

    @Override
    public void registerDestructionCallback(String name, Runnable callback, int scope) {}

    @Override
    public Object resolveReference(String key) { return null; }

    @Override
    public String getSessionId() { return null; }

    @Override
    public Object getSessionMutex() { return null; }
}
```

Now at the start of the request in your code, instruct the `RequestContextHolder` to use this `CustomRequestAttribute` by executing the following statement and in the finally block clear out the request attributes.

```java
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 7 * * *")
public void doSomething() {
    try {
        RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(
                new CustomRequestAttribute());
        userService.getSomeUsersIds
                .forEach(userService::doSomething);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // ...
    } finally {
        RequestContextHolder.resetRequestAttributes();
    }
}
```